# Percentage on map for Berneside Plains

Tags: guardian-cross

[image: berneside plains]

What does the 80% mean below Berneside Plains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the percentage of guardians that can be found in that zone that are in your catalogue so far. Confirmed in several zones against catalogue counts.

Comment: The sad part is the %age catalog completion tracks everything including 5*s - so without heavy borrowing/trading, its almost impossible to get 100% :(

Comment: Yeah, but that's not a big deal for a *trading* card game. Usually people on the forums will lend you a 5* if you have one for them to hold as collateral.